# if class not found return none in beatifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get `None` if the class is not found in web scraping. For example, in some cases `stage-codes.html#10_99` doesn't exist in HTML.

```
for st in soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "dropdown-menu"}):
    for k in st.find_all("a", {"href": "/stage-codes.html#10_99"},limit=1):
      a = k.find("span", class_='stage-date').getText()
      print(a)
      try:
        start_date.append(a) 
      except:
        start_date.append(None)
```

The 3rd index's start_date must be None instead of data of 4th index:

[image]

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question with some more details, so that everybody could reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to read: How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, **If find() can’t find anything, it returns `None`**

So, assuming there's not an error in how you're setting up your for loops, you should be able to try something link this:

```
for st in soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "dropdown-menu"}):
for k in st.find_all("a", {"href": "/stage-codes.html#10_99"},limit=1):
  a = k.find("span", class_='stage-date')
  try:
    a_text = a.get_text()
    print(a_text)
    start_date.append(a_text) 
  except:
    start_date.append(None)
```

But since nothing is getting appended at this point then I would say one of your loops isn't getting triggered at all

Answer (score 0):

You put `limit=1` so if `/stage-codes.html#10_99` is found, the length of `x` here will be 1. You can check that with an `if` statement. Also, I believe `None` should be a string.

```
for st in soup.find_all("ul", class_= "dropdown-menu"):
    x = st.find_all('a', href="/stage-codes.html#10_99", limit=1)
    if len(x) == 1:
        for k in x:
            a = k.find("span", class_='stage-date').getText()
            print(a)
            start_date.append(a) 
    else:
        start_date.append("None")
```